# Objective C: Compare two enum types not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, enums

I would like to do a check for two enum types, but it doesn't seem to work. I have the following:

```
typedef enum {
    ZSSegmentTypeE,
    ZSSegmentTypeS,
    ZSSegmentTypeO,
    ZSSegmentTypeD,
    ZSSegmentTypeN
} ZSSegmentType;
```

The following WORKS:

```
if (someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeN) {
    // Works
}
```

The following DOES NOT WORK:

```
if (someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeN || someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeD) {
     // Does NOT work
}
```

Why doesn't this second example work, where I am testing two different enums? What am I missing in understanding how enums and comparisons work?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? `x != a || x != b` will always be true.

Comment: Ok, looks like I am mistaken by my own code. It has been a long day...

Answer (score 5):

[De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) tells you, that this:

```
someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeN || someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeD
```

is the same as this:

```
!(someSegmentType == ZSSegmentTypeN && someSegmentType == ZSSegmentTypeD)
```

I'm sure you realize that `someSegmentType` can't be both `ZSSegmentTypeN` *and* `ZSSegmentTypeD` at the same time. Thus the expression in the brackets will always be false and the whole statement will be true.

What you probably want to test is wether that variable is neither of those two values. You do that like this:

```
someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeN && someSegmentType != ZSSegmentTypeD
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the second if-statement to only succeed if someSegmentType is neither of the two values then you want &&, not ||.